# Redirecting user to menu section, after button click, by popping up nav bar from the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, button, menu, navigation

Thanks to Rene for the first part that works now. :)

I have a bug that I don't know how to fix:

- its job is to pop up nav bar from the bottom of the screen for half of second so that user know where it is and than it gets back down after half a second
- then user can hover over it and it pops up automatically and stays up as long as mouse is on it, and on mouse out it gets to its first position.

Problem:
***after button action, hover animation doesn't work anymore, is that because JS overwrites CSS nav:hover, and if so do you maybe know how to fix it. Thank you for help really helps a lot!

and here is JS code:

```
//nav popup

const navHover = function navHover() {
  const nav = document.getElementById("nav");

  nav.style.transition = "all 1s";
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Menu button

const openNav = function openNav() {
  const menuButton = document.getElementById("menuButton");
  const nav = document.getElementById("nav");

    nav.style.height = "50px";
    console.log("to 50px");

    setTimeout(function navBackDown() {
      nav.style.height = "10px";
      console.log("to 10px");
    }, 600);
};
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: On the first click `menuButton` uses the `openNav` function to attach the `menuButton.addEventListener` to itself. The second click that attached `eventListener("click")` gets triggered. So, essentially, you built in the 'double click'. FYI, we're not going to download, install and debug your github code to find an error, it's not how SO works. Missed how to post a [reprex]?

Comment: Oh, sorry my fault, that was just so you can see everything if you want to. My bad, and thank you for explaining , so I'm gonna remove second part with eventListener("click"), should that fix that not responsivnes of the nav bar, and tnx again

Answer (score 0):

I have got it :) thank you Rene once more for help

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//nav popup

const navHover = function navHover() {
  const nav = document.getElementById("nav");
  console.log("hovered")
  
  nav.style.height = "80px";
  nav.style.transition = "all 1s";
  
};

function navOut(){
  nav.style.height = "10px";
  console.log("to 10px");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Menu button

const openNav = function openNav() {
  const menuButton = document.getElementById("menuButton");
  const nav = document.getElementById("nav");


    nav.style.height = "50px";
    console.log("to 50px");

    setTimeout(function navBackDown() {
      nav.style.height = "10px";
      console.log("to 10px");
    }, 600);
    
};
```

I don't exactly know why but when I "gave it some time" in between it just worked :)